# avoid menu breaking in small window size and let the page scroll

Tags: html, css, menu, scroll, responsive-design

Here is what I don’t want to happen, in my responsive design:

[design http://imgs.ir/imgs/201307/break_2_.png](http://imgs.ir/imgs/201307/break_2_.png)

**And want the page scroll.**

*It’s possible to have a jsfiddle if need.*

Comment: Scroll horizontally? It looks like it already scrolls vertically.

Comment: I want to let the page scroll (horizontally), but it break the menu and prevent my page to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/2G9ze/

I edited the CSS, adding whitespace:no-wrap to the nav and fine-tuned the results on narrow screens by adding a media query.

**CSS changes**

```
.nav-wrapper {
float: right;
white-space: nowrap;
}  

@media screen and (max-width: 375px){

.nav-wrapper {
float: left;
 min-width:375px;
}
}
```

Comment: I couldn't take help from those. Please take a look at its jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jDTQG/ try to small the browser width and see the menu breaking.

Comment: It wasn't clear from you original question what you were looking for. See my updated answer

Comment: Your jsfiddle is OK in google chrome, but it still break the menu in Firefox.

Comment: You're correct ;) I updated the example to account for this blip in Firefox

Comment: Did you update the jsfiddle link? It breaks in FF yet.

Comment: Using min-width:320px solved my problem easily :)

Comment: That's perfect @Farzad